# How to show cursor during application debug c OpenGl on ubuntu in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, opengl, glfw

```
window = glfwCreateWindow(winW, winH, "TestApp", NULL, NULL);
```

After calling this command, the mouse cursor disappears. When a breakpoint is triggered after this command, I can not fully use the debug. How to show cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new, v1.67, setting:

`Debug: Focus Editor on Break`    It is enabled by default.

> Controls whether the editor should be focused when the debugger
> breaks.

will help.

From [When a breakpoint is hit, the caret (cursor) should move to that line](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139950)